# Gate - extracting individual annotated text from annotation set

Tags: java, filewriter, gate

I'm trying to extract the individual text values of an annotation set which are generated by the default ANNIE processing resources.

When i iterate through the annotation set each entry only gives the start and end position which the annotation references but does not give a .value() method. Is there an easy way to get the value or do i need to use a FileWriter or some equivalent to extract the value directly from the Corpus I'm processing using the start and end positions of the annotation?

```
annotTypesRequired.add("Location");

Set<Annotation> organization = new HashSet<Annotation>(
                defaultAnnotSet.get(annotTypesRequired));
```

Comment: Something like: 
`gate.AnnotationSet entityAS = 
(gate.AnnotationSet)bindings.get("entity");
gate.Annotation entityAnn = (gate.Annotation)entityAS.iterator().next();
gate.FeatureMap features = Factory.newFeatureMap();
features.put("type", entityAnn.getType());outputAS.add(entityAnn.getStartNode(), entityAnn.getEndNode(), 
"Entity“, features);`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If by "the value" you mean the text that the annotation covers, you can access that using

```
gate.Utils.stringFor(document, annotation)
```

For this you obviously need a reference to the `gate.Document` that the annotation belongs to, as well as the `Annotation` object itself - annotations do not routinely store their covered string directly, they just store offsets that point into the document's content.

Comment: The method `gate.Utils.stringFor` has been very useful to me in order to access to the _meta-property_ `@string` of a Lookup annotation.